# Getting results from table-valued Postgresql function with JOOQ

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I have a Postgresql function that returns Table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func(IN param1 text, IN param2 integer)
  RETURNS TABLE(result1 text, result2 integer) AS
  $BODY$
  BEGIN
   result1 := 'aa';
   result2 :=1;
   return next;
   result1 := 'bb';
   result2 :=2;
   return next;
  END
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Query in pg-admin returns correct result

```
select * from test_func('aaa', 23);
result1 | result2
"aa"    | 1
"bb"    | 2
```

JOOQ generates function as always

```
...
public class TestFunc extends org.jooq.impl.AbstractRoutine<java.lang.Void> {
...
public TestFunc() {
    super("test_func", ee.tavex.tavexwise.db.public_.Public.PUBLIC);

    addInParameter(PARAM1);
    addInParameter(PARAM2);
    addOutParameter(RESULT1);
    addOutParameter(RESULT2);
}
...
```

and in Routines class

```
...
public static ee.tavex.tavexwise.db.public_.routines.TestFunc testFunc(org.jooq.Configuration configuration, java.lang.String param1, java.lang.Integer param2) {
    ee.tavex.tavexwise.db.public_.routines.TestFunc p = new ee.tavex.tavexwise.db.public_.routines.TestFunc();
    p.setParam1(param1);
    p.setParam2(param2);

    p.execute(configuration);
    return p;
}
```

I call it this way

```
TestFunc records = Routines.testFunc(dslConfiguration, "xx", 10);


records.getResults()  //returns empty List
records.getResult1() //returns "aa"
records.getResult2() //returns 1
```

So, it correctly returns the first row's values, but how can I get the whole table?

(jooq 3.5.0)

Comment: No. I'm trying to make the request using JOOQ renerated routines. Now the one generated is identical to the one I get, when function returns only one Record. I can't get result described here http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.5/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/table-valued-functions/

Comment: @user693442: Can you show the jOOQ code that you're using? Can you also show the function body, just to be sure there's nothing wrong in there?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Interesting, I don't get that particular `testFunc(Configuration, String, Integer)` method ([see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28405424/521799)). There might be a subtle bug. Would you mind taking this over to the [jOOQ User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jooq-user)? It will be easier to discuss further steps to see what might have caused the bug (perhaps the PostgreSQL version?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to call table-valued functions from jOOQ is by using them in `FROM` clauses [as documented in the manual page](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/table-valued-functions/) that you've linked.

In your case, that would be:

```
Result<TestFuncRecord> result =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .selectFrom(Routines.testFunc("xx", 10))
   .fetch();
```

Or starting with jOOQ 3.6 also

```
Result<TestFuncRecord> result =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .selectFrom(Tables.TEST_FUNC("xx", 10))
   .fetch();
```

The jOOQ code generator treats table-valued functions like ordinary tables, not like routines. This is why there should be no method in `Routines` that takes a `Configuration` argument.

Comment: @user693442 thanks for accepting. What was the actual problem you had? I.e. did you find out what produced the "wrong" generated routines?

Comment: I had several jooq jar's of different version in my classpath. 
And second problem is with overloaded table-valued procedures. I posted a separate question for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28434559/jooq-not-generating-table-valued-overloaded-procedures-from-postgresql

Comment: @user693442: Hmm, yes that could certainly cause issues... Thanks for the feedback