# JOOQ not generating table-valued overloaded procedures from PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I have several `table-valued` `overloaded` procedures in my `PostgreSql` database. They have the same name, but different number of parameters. As `JOOQ 3.5` treats those procedures `as tables`, generator discovers `only one procedure` with that name. Is it designed this way, or is there a workaround?

`GeneratorStrategy` doesn't help as this happens earlier, when `database.getTables(schema)` in `Generator` is Called.

Comment: You won't stop finding bugs, will you? :) thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug ([#4055](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4055)) in jOOQ 3.5.2. jOOQ currently doesn't support overloaded table-valued functions.

The only workaround I can think of is to resort to [plain SQL](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/) for those functions.