# Query from user defined function JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I'm looking to query from user defined function. All the example I've seen are querying the function as `select` parameter

```
myFunction.setMyParam("plapla");
create.select(myFunction.asField()).fetch();
```

This return the result as one column although the result is actually multiple columns.

What I would like to do is

```
myFunction.setMyParam("plapla");
create.select().from(myFunction).fetch();
```

But I have not found a way to do so...

Currently I'm using

```
DSL.using(create.configuration())
                .select()
                .from("myFunction('" + myparam + "')")
                .fetch();
```

and this does not seem like a good solution (unescaped, untreated etc.)

How to do it using JOOQ generated function?

Comment: Table valued functions are highly dependent on the SQL dialect in jOOQ. What database are you using? Also, could you show the signature of your `MY_FUNCTION` as you declared it in your database?

Comment: Using postgres and `MY_FUNCTION(text, integer, text)`

Comment: Probably related to this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28383480/getting-results-from-table-valued-postgresql-function-with-jooq

My function returns table
`RETURNS TABLE(myParams text) AS $BODY$`

`myFunction.execute(configuration()); myFunction.getMyParameter();`
returns only the first row.. Using JOOQ 3.8.3

Comment: You know you can edit your question :)

Comment: I figured you won't get a notification if I edit?

Comment: You can edit and then ping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ generates function calls for PostgreSQL table valued functions. If your function looks like this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_function(text, integer, text)
RETURNS TABLE (myParams text) AS ...
```

Then jOOQ produces the following method:

```java
public class Tables {
    ...
    public static MyFunction myFunction(String param1, Integer param2, String param3) 
    { ... }
}
```

Which you can then call as such:

```java
Result<MyFunctionRecord> result =
DSL.using(create.configuration())
   .selectFrom(myFunction("a", 1, "b")
   .fetch();
```

The resulting record will be of the form:

```java
public class MyFunctionRecord {
    ...
    public String getMyParams() { ... }
}
```

Comment: My function is as you mentioned but it's not published under Tables, it's under routines

Comment: I see, there's a flag for that in the code generator config to have it also under Tables. It doesn't matter, though.

Comment: Setting `<tableValuedFunctions>true</tableValuedFunctions>` worked

Answer (score 1):

I had to turn off generating table valued functions for now because of the infamous

> java: variable XYZ is already defined in class

I was able to accomplish the above like

```
create
    .selectFrom( Routines.myFunction(myparam).toString() )
```

I hope to get the table valued functions generating properly, because the above answer is better, but this will work in the meantime.